# python: быстрый способ накопить в словаре списки значений

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

есть задача:

дан список чисел, необходимо собрать словарь, в котором в качестве ключа выступает число из списка, а в качестве значения - список позиций данного числа в исходном списке

подскажите, есть ли более производительный код, чем решение в лоб:

```
res = dict()
for i, v in enumerate(arr):
    if v in arr:
        res[v].append(i)
    else:
        res[v] = [i]
```

если использовать `get` - это замедляет код в 2-3 раза:

```
res = dict()
for i, v in enumerate(arr):
    res[v] = res.get(v, []) + [i]
```

Comment: Что такое `pathes`?

Comment: А вообще при замене проверки ключа в словаре на `try / except KeyError` у меня получилось на 20% быстрее

Comment: как на счет генератора?

Comment: Вариант с `+` тем хуже, чем больше одинаковых значений в массиве. `arr= [0] * 1000000` вас удивит.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вот да, `+` что для строк, что для списков это очень нехорошо

Comment: @andreymal, исправил - просто старое название :)

Comment: @andreymal, с try/except у меня тоже время выходит

Comment: @Zhihar видимо, зависит от повторяемости чисел в исходном списке. Если уникальных чисел немного, то try/except быстрее, а если много, то медленнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из того, что я попробовал на моих тестовых данных быстрее оказался `defaultdict`. Но вообще нужно всё-таки приводить параметры ваших данных: тип и размерность. На разных данных могут быть разные результаты.

```py
import random
from collections import defaultdict

def func1(arr):
    res = dict()
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        if v in res:
            res[v].append(i)
        else:
            res[v] = [i]

def func2(arr):
    res = dict()
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        res[v] = res.get(v, []) + [i]

def func3(arr):
    res = dict()
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        res.setdefault(v, []).append(i)

def func4(arr):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        res[v].append(i)

arr = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(1000)]
assert func1(arr) == func2(arr)
assert func2(arr) == func3(arr)
assert func3(arr) == func4(arr)

%timeit func1(arr)
%timeit func2(arr)
%timeit func3(arr)
%timeit func4(arr)
```

Вывод:

```
10000 loops, best of 5: 167 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 270 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 5: 192 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 5: 144 µs per loop
```

С `itertools.groupby` я что-то недоразобрался )

Так то хорошо бы ещё попробовать `Numpy` и `Numba`, но нужно знать, какие у вас данные.

Comment: Перед `itertools.groupby` вам придётся сортировать исходный список. Что плохо.

Comment: @CrazyElf, данные - обычные целые числа, но очень много

Comment: @Zhihar из какого диапазона и каков порядок количества чисел? Это может быть важно.